# Question about roasting green beans and cherry tomatoes

Tags: tomatoes, roasting

I have a question about something new I want to try for Thanksgiving.

Everyone things we're making too many casseroles and asked me to do something different. I decided to try to replace the green been casserole. I had some roasted green beans and cherry tomatoes as Red Lobster last year and really liked them. I think they'd be a great and easy substitute. I'm not exactly sure what they did to them, but it was probably just olive oil, salt, pepper, and maybe some garlic.

My question is about cooking these two items together. I assume it would be more flavorful to cook them together as the juices would combine, but I'd really like to get good caramelization on my cherry tomatoes, but I still want to green beans to have some bite.

I feel like if I cook them together that either the green beans would end up mushy and the tomatoes caramelized, or the green beans would be good, but the tomatoes wouldn't be caramelized.

Does anyone who's made this know how this will turn out? Should I start the tomatoes first, to give them a head start, then add the green beans, or is it necessary?

I bought enough ingredients to do one test batch. They don't have to be the star of the table, I just want them to be good. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I would roast the tomatoes until they're nearly at the desired caramelisation, and meanwhile blanch the beans. Then pop the beans in with the tomatoes for 5-10 minutes at the end so they can get to know each other.

Comment: What temperature would you cook them at? I've been seeing 425-450.

Comment: Yeah, I'd go quite hot. Help evaporate the moisture and improve caramelisation. Tomatoes give off a _lot_ of water. You might even need to put the pan on the stove and get some heat underneath it to reduce it down to a sauce.